# How to copy cell formatting with values in a FILTER across sheets (tabs) in google spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula

I have a big table of data in `sheet1` whose values and styling I'd like to filter down in a separate `sheet2` to see a more restricted subset.

The formula I'm using works fine to copy the filtered data over, based on a search key in `sheet2!B1` (basically copying the entire row of data when something in sheet1 column B is blank, or if column C matches my constraint in `sheet2!B1`):

```
=FILTER('sheet1'!B:Q, if(isblank('sheet1'!B:B), true, 'sheet1'!C:C = B1))
```

However, no styles are copied at all. Is there another built-in function that can copy the formatting as well, or a simple custom function that can be attached somehow to copy the values & styles?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind an Apps Script to the Spreadsheet [1] and assuming the source format is in the first sheet of the Spreadsheet and the target range is in the 2nd sheet, you can run this function:

```
function formatIt() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var destination = ss.getSheets()[1];

  var range = source.getRange("B2:D4");
  range.copyFormatToRange(destination, 4, 6, 4, 6);  
}
```

That would copy the format from cells "B2:D4" to "D4:F6" using the copyFormatToRange function [2].

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#copyformattorangesheet,-column,-columnend,-row,-rowend